# Submit and create an order on checkout via ajax in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I added a button to Checkout form :

```
<input type="submit" id="ajax-order-btn" class="button" value="Place Order via AJAX" />
```

and added a AJAX snippet in `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'ajax_call_place_order');
function ajax_call_place_order() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(document).on("click", "#ajax-order-btn" ,function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var data = {
                    action: 'ajax_order',
                };

                $.post('<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

And this is AJAX callback with which create a order programmatically:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'ajax_order_callback_wp');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'ajax_order_callback_wp' );
function ajax_order_callback_wp() {

    $address = array(
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name'  => 'Doe',
        'company'    => 'Speed Society',
        'email'      => 'joe@testing.com',
        'phone'      => '760-555-1212',
        'address_1'  => '123 Main st.',
        'address_2'  => '104',
        'city'       => 'San Diego',
        'state'      => 'Ca',
        'postcode'   => '92121',
        'country'    => 'US'
    );


    $order = wc_create_order();

    $order->add_product( get_product('275962'), 1); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->update_status("Completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);
}
```

**The problem** is that I can't find a way to get current order data, and to use that data when creating order programmatically instead of current hardcoded data. I need to place exact same order as the current one on Checkout page.

I was trying with `WC_Checkout`, and methods  `create_order()` and `get_checkout_fields()`,  but no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For PHP order creation I use a custom clone from WC_Checkout `create_order()` method that works perfectly. All submitted data is automatically set in the order.

For custom order meta data and custom order item meta data, you can use all woocommerce default hooks as:

- `woocommerce_checkout_create_order`
- `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`
- `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`
- *and so on …*

I have also made some necessary changes in the jQuery code to make it work nicely, sending the necessary formatted data to PHP via Ajax*(which is now in the footer)*.

The complete code that create an order via Ajax:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'checkout_billing_email_js_ajax' );
function checkout_billing_email_js_ajax() {
    // Only on Checkout
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined') 
            return false;

        $(document.body).on("click", "#ajax-order-btn" ,function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type:    'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                data: {
                    'action': 'ajax_order',
                    'fields': $('form.checkout').serializeArray(),
                    'user_id': <?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result); // For testing (to be removed)
                },
                error:   function(error) {
                    console.log(error); // For testing (to be removed)
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'submited_ajax_order_data');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'submited_ajax_order_data' );
function submited_ajax_order_data() {
    if( isset($_POST['fields']) && ! empty($_POST['fields']) ) {

        $order    = new WC_Order();
        $cart     = WC()->cart;
        $checkout = WC()->checkout;
        $data     = [];

        // Loop through posted data array transmitted via jQuery
        foreach( $_POST['fields'] as $values ){
            // Set each key / value pairs in an array
            $data[$values['name']] = $values['value'];
        }

        $cart_hash          = md5( json_encode( wc_clean( $cart->get_cart_for_session() ) ) . $cart->total );
        $available_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();

        // Loop through the data array
        foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
            // Use WC_Order setter methods if they exist
            if ( is_callable( array( $order, "set_{$key}" ) ) ) {
                $order->{"set_{$key}"}( $value );

            // Store custom fields prefixed with wither shipping_ or billing_
            } elseif ( ( 0 === stripos( $key, 'billing_' ) || 0 === stripos( $key, 'shipping_' ) )
                && ! in_array( $key, array( 'shipping_method', 'shipping_total', 'shipping_tax' ) ) ) {
                $order->update_meta_data( '_' . $key, $value );
            }
        }

        $order->set_created_via( 'checkout' );
        $order->set_cart_hash( $cart_hash );
        $order->set_customer_id( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_customer_id', isset($_POST['user_id']) ? $_POST['user_id'] : '' ) );
        $order->set_currency( get_woocommerce_currency() );
        $order->set_prices_include_tax( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_prices_include_tax' ) );
        $order->set_customer_ip_address( WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address() );
        $order->set_customer_user_agent( wc_get_user_agent() );
        $order->set_customer_note( isset( $data['order_comments'] ) ? $data['order_comments'] : '' );
        $order->set_payment_method( isset( $available_gateways[ $data['payment_method'] ] ) ? $available_gateways[ $data['payment_method'] ]  : $data['payment_method'] );
        $order->set_shipping_total( $cart->get_shipping_total() );
        $order->set_discount_total( $cart->get_discount_total() );
        $order->set_discount_tax( $cart->get_discount_tax() );
        $order->set_cart_tax( $cart->get_cart_contents_tax() + $cart->get_fee_tax() );
        $order->set_shipping_tax( $cart->get_shipping_tax() );
        $order->set_total( $cart->get_total( 'edit' ) );

        $checkout->create_order_line_items( $order, $cart );
        $checkout->create_order_fee_lines( $order, $cart );
        $checkout->create_order_shipping_lines( $order, WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ), WC()->shipping->get_packages() );
        $checkout->create_order_tax_lines( $order, $cart );
        $checkout->create_order_coupon_lines( $order, $cart );

        /**
         * Action hook to adjust order before save.
         * @since 3.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data );

        // Save the order.
        $order_id = $order->save();

        do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', $order_id, $data );

        echo 'New order created with order ID: #'.$order_id.'.' ;
    }
    die();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

Make your JS function to post the checkout field data as well and capture the data from `$_POST`

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).on("click", "#ajax-order-btn" ,function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var post_data: $( 'form.checkout' ).serialize()
            var data = {
                action: 'ajax_order',
                post_data : post_data
            };

            $.post('<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I'm not sure if I understood your answer correctly, but I don't think this is a solution because client may add new fields or edit current field names, and I also need products and variations, and other data.

Comment: I just edited title and "the problem" part related to this.

Comment: It's not a solution because I don't know what will be the exact names of the fields in the future. And it doesn't pass other order data - products, variations, prices...